# Why it is necessary to create only single instance of SessionFactory?

Tags: nhibernate

my code is

```
static {
    try {
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

here i created only single instance of SessionFactory

the above code work correctly but why we create only single instance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of creating a session factory is expensive, performance wise. The performance gain from using a single static session factory is at least an order of magnitude. You can certainly create a new factory on each request, if you'd like, but it would be incredibly wasteful to do so.